# Inserting data from CSV into MySQL DB is very slow

Tags: mysql, ruby, performance

Trying to insert data from a CSV file to a MySQL DB using Ruby, and it's very slow. Note that this is not a Rails application, just stand-alone Ruby script.

Here is my code:

```
def add_record (data1, data2, time)
    date = DateTime.strptime(time, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
    <my table>.create(data1: data1, data2: data2, time: date)
end

def parse_file (file)
    path = @folder + "\\" + file
    CSV.foreach(path, {headers: :first_row}) do |line|
        add_record(line[4], line[5], line[0])
    end
end

def analyze_data ()
    Dir.foreach @folder do |file|
        next if file == '.' or file == '..'
        parse_file file
    end     
end
```

And my connection:

```
@connection = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(  
  :adapter=> "mysql2",  
  :host => "localhost",  
  :database=> <db>,
  :username => "root",
  :password => <pw>
)
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I wrote [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32702768) up for a fella. Took his 8 hr import down to a minute or so. Seems extreme, but that is what he said.

Comment: MUCH FASTER! Thanks!

Comment: awesome, glad to hear it !

Comment: Final score: 3 days to 30 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Load Data Infile](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

Here is a nice article on performance and strategies titled [Testing the Fastest Way to Import a Table into MySQL](http://dbahire.com/testing-the-fastest-way-to-import-a-table-into-mysql-and-some-interesting-5-7-performance-results/). Don't let the mysql version of the title or inside the article scare you away. Jumping to the bottom and picking up some conclusions:

> The fastest way you can import a table into MySQL without using raw
>   files is the LOAD DATA syntax. Use parallelization for InnoDB for
>   better results, and remember to tune basic parameters like your
>   transaction log size and buffer pool. Careful programming and
>   importing can make a >2-hour problem became a 2-minute process. You
>   can disable temporarily some security features for extra performance

You might just find your times greatly reduced.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [zdennis/activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) gem. you can insert tons records quickly.